# Small Red Vase W/ Chinese on bottom?

Tags: translation

Can someone help me decipher these characters? These are on a small red vase with a small "wick" attached to the top.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Left: **乾**
- Right: **隆**
- Top: **年**
- Bottom: **制**

You read the characters as if you are standing at the center. The order is a bit funny because it's what people in antiquity do. It is read as **乾隆年制** -- "**Made in the year of Qian Long**". Qian Long(乾隆) is an emperor of 清(Qing) dynasty.

It is a form of 篆書. You see a lot of such imprints in antiquities. Take a look at this:

[image]

it says:

> 年|乾|大
>
> 制|隆|清